# Is there any case law that sets the minimum amount in controversy to the minimum amount permissible to settle in class actions?

Tags: united-states, settlement, class-action, punitive-damages, civil-penalty

There, of course, are such a compensatory-to-punitive damages ratio principle — even if merely in the form of fairly complex guideposts for e.g. the BMW guidepost, the just less-less-than-10x of Johnson v. Ford, etc. because it is within the forefront of public interest to prevent sentient corporate America from cruel punishments, but is there a similar at-least—x-fraction-of-amount-in-controversy with a similarly tactile set of rules for a court to *not* approve a class settlement and allow only proceeding to trial?

For e.g., if the class is preponderated by members of financially vulnerable individuals, *or* if the median amounts in controversy per member exceeds a certain proportion of the median income (e.g. a quarter of it), *or* if it relates to the liquidation of restitution for employment or substantially similar contracts *or* any other such rules that latitude of a court to approve a settlement once a complaint is file.

In other words: Are there similar complex rules to protect the average Joe too from greedy companies who appear to be basically hit the whole flock of birds with a stone kept while lawyers for the plaintiff work out a new Lambo or a house out of a 35% share of a few mill?

How is this very apparent conflict of interest resolved?

Comment: If the plaintiff's attorneys get a percentage of the amount collected, then it's in their interests to get as much as possible.  Their interests are directly aligned with those of the plaintiffs; I'm not sure where you see a conflict.  Settling for a fraction of what you really want is normal and happens in all sorts of cases, not just class actions.

Comment: I'd suggest a rewrite of your question - it's very rambling and hard to follow.

Comment: There are precedents where purely nominal awards of compensatory damages (say $1 in the US or one penny in the UK) are coupled with very large punitive awards.

Comment: @NateEldredge Not necessarily. It might be more in their interest to settle quickly for half the sum and only do a quarter of the work. That way they can settle 4 cases in the same time and get twice the income of fighting one. Economists call this the principal-agent problem.

Comment: The question so heavily blurs opinion based questions and statements and legal ones that it hard to tell what is being asked.

Comment: @DaleM PRECISELY! ...the proportions are probably more damning

Comment: @ohwilleke Nate Eldredge I’m gonna have to yield to these comments, apologies. I just see so many of the gig workers getting robbed their eyes blind only for a couple of crooks decide they no longer have claim and throw a rotten apple at them in return

Comment: There are rules on the *number* of class members needed to be a class action, that much I know

Answer (score 1):

### [Yes](https://www.slatergordon.com.au/class-actions/class-actions-101)

[australia](/questions/tagged/australia)

> In Australia, class action settlements require the approval of the Court before they can take effect. The representative plaintiff will make an application to the Court to approve a proposed settlement, in which they will need to provide the Court with a significant amount of information about the settlement, how it was reached, and what it will mean for group members.
>
> The Court will generally be concerned with answering two main kinds of question about a settlement:
>
> 1. Is it a fair and reasonable settlement considering the claims made on behalf of the group members?
> 2. Has the settlement been reached in the interests of group members as well as the representative plaintiff, and not just in the interests of the representative and the defendant?

Comment: I guess the same is true for the U.S., it’s just a matter of how much of this actually manifest into substantive action.